# Finding out the best concentration for my plant extract to be used as drug for diabetes

Tags: botany, medicine, biotechnology, glucose, diabetes-mellitus

I am using plant extract of Ajuga parviflora and found out that it possess anti-diabetic properties by using alpha-amylase inhibitory assay. I used various concentration 250 µg/ml(29% inhibiton of alpha-amylase), 500µg/ml(37%),750µg/ml(46%) and 1000µg/ml(63%). Basically, alpha-amylase results in increase in glucose level after eating food. So  i wanted to know that how could i find out that what is the best concentration of my plant extract to be used as drug.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Is it?

Comment: No, i am in my final year of my btech working on a plant and when a plant report some property then it is better if we can also give its best concentration.

Answer (score 2):

You have to try to determine the best concentration.

Usually there are multiple [clinical trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_trial), first in animals, then in humans to

1. figure out the effective dose
2. look for side effects
3. compare the new drug's efficacy with existing drugs

Comment: I think this is better as a comment as it doesn't answer the question which in any case looks very like a homework question.

Comment: @David Actually I started writing a comment first and was expecting a "please don't answer in comments" response :) And it didn't occur to me this could be homework.

Comment: @David Owh, and the answer was: _You have to try._

Comment: "humen"? spelling is human...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, was confused by the man/men and woman/women plural.